# Meteor - rxjs@5.0.0-beta.11 or rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6 UNMET DEPENDENCY

Tags: node.js, meteor, angular, npm

i have this problem with meteor project with angular2, if i install ( with meteor npm install ) the package rxjs5.0.0-beta.11 the nam says:

`@angular/router@3.0.0-alpha.8 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6 but none was installed.`

If i install the package rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6 the nam says : 
"

```
npm WARN @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.6 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.11 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular2-google-maps@0.14.0 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.11 but none was installed.
```

"

Typical answer of the problem "dog chasing its tail", if i install the beta.11 it's required beta.6 and if i install beta.6 the requirements it's beta.11 
This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "angular2-meteor-base",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "meteor run",
    "test": "meteor test --driver-package practicalmeteor:mocha",
    "test:ci": "meteor test --once --driver-package dispatch:mocha-phantomjs"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "3.5.0",
    "chai-spies": "0.7.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-alpha.8",
    "angular2-google-maps": "^0.14.0",
    "angular2-meteor": "0.6.2",
    "angular2-meteor-accounts-ui": "^0.6.1",
    "angular2-meteor-auto-bootstrap": "0.6.0",
    "angular2-meteor-polyfills": "0.1.1",
    "angular2-meteor-tests-polyfills": "0.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.1",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "0.2.3",
    "ng2-pagination": "^0.3.5",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "0.6.12"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your package.json?

Comment: Add package.json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update these 3 in your package.json

```
"@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.2",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.11",
"zone.js": "^0.6.17"
```

You can refer latest package.json [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html#!#add-config-files)

See if this helps.

Comment: This is very helpful, your link is very helpful. I solve problem on package dep. and now. Thanks